# How can I catch an inserted value of any input field (without having #id) on the fly?

Tags: jquery

I have a form with over 100 input fields. Their labels show the quantity in stock. Now I want to write a logic which is catching every inserted value in a field (without submitting the form), compare it with its label and if its > label it supposed to set the color in red.

How can I create a function which is catching a) the input field b) the added value on the fly?

I tried:

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var inp = jQuery("*:focus").val();
    alert(inp);
    var label = jQuery('label[for="'+jQuery(this)+'"]');
    alert(label);
  });
</script>
```

But that gives me just an undefined. Any help is much appreciated.
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You sure you don't really want a key handler for that, so the input currently being typed in is validated etc

Comment: What's the HTML structure of input-label?

Comment: `$(this)` will not return the input, it will return the container, or `document`.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. Below snippet works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't target the focused element, but use an event handler for input instead, and then check if the value is more than the label (strings are okay when using `>` or `<`) and set it's color

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('input').on('input', function() {
        var lbl  = $('label[for="' + this.id + '"]'),
            more = this.value > lbl.text();

        lbl.css('color', (more ? 'red' : 'black'));
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/j5ws8odj/)